# Change imageview depending on which imageview clicked before

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

In my main activity I got 2 imageviews (imageview1 and imageview2). If i click one of them It starts a new activity. In the new activity i also got an imageview. I want that it changes to the imageview which i hold.

I know i can change an imageview with

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

If i would hold imageview1 in the new activity it should be

```
    imageView.setImageResource(imageview1);
```

and if i hold imageview2

```
    imageView.setImageResource(imageview2);
```

but i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

1. When imageview 1 is clicked and when you start your Intent send a value to your next activity

   for example

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent(...);
   i.putExtra("image","imageview1")
   ```
2. In the other Activity,

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent();
   String image = i.getExtras().getString("image");

   switch(image){
    case "imageview1": 
    //display imageview 1
    break;
    case "imageview2":
    //display imageview 2
    break;
   }
   ```

Comment: Why not set the id of the image in the intent ?

Comment: @danypata can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: He's displaying images from resources, thus those images have an id, which is an int :) So I was thinking just send that id trough the bundle :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably start activity by `intent` you can s image resource id in intent by `putExtra()` method and in the second activity you get starting intent by calling `getIntent()` method and get it by calling `getExtra()` method

Answer (score 0):

If the image is just from resource, use the resource id to show on the second activity.

I mean, 1st activity, you set the resource id, depending in click on image1 or image2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

if (click image1) {
    intent.putExtra("IMAGE_TO_SHOW", R.mipmap.ic_launcher1);
} else {
    intent.putExtra("IMAGE_TO_SHOW", R.mipmap.ic_launcher2);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

And in the second activity, just take the id and put in the new ImageView:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int imageResource = intent.getIntExtra("IMAGE_TO_SHOW", R.mipmap.ic_launcher1);
imageViewOnActivity2.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Comment: How i define "click image1" ?

Comment: It depends how are you handling the clicks. I ment that when click on image1, put resource id of the image1, and when click on image2, put resource id of the image2